# How to call functions/set data in a game from an external program. (Skyrim)

Tags: memory, reverse, inject, game-development

I was wondering if there is any possible way to call functions in a running process from an external process. I'm trying to write myself a program right now to call console commands in Skyrim from an external process. The console itself in Skyrim is pretty wimpy, and I thought I could make a program with a GUI that would allow me to do things like add items or equip weapons. I have 3 ideas to doing this, which are calling the code directly (?), altering the running memory for things like inventory, equipped items, etc., or just sending keystrokes to quickly type the console commands. I'd prefer to do the 1st method if there is any way how, because it seems the most direct. I've seemed to have located the console commands in the executable using IDA decompiler, but I have no clue what to do next.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Any help at all, or links or articles, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Glen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! [Skyrim Script Dragon](http://alexander.sannybuilder.com/?category=other&altname=skyrim_script_dragon) allows you to execute C++ code from Skyrim and call Skyrim commands from C++.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, I think you need to work with ASM, and have knowledge of the way the Skyrim console works. Check if the console is open-sourced with code available to download for free. Otherwise use something like REC Studio or IDA to decompile your exe (and create a patch with the functionality you are looking for.